# Scrollview vertical only with fixed width in Autolayout

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

In swift how can I set the width of the scroll view to be the width of the screen size?

I tried setting right leading and trailing bounds, but my aspectscalefill image keeps stretching the entire frame.

I am trying to force the view to be the width of the screen and allow vertical scrolling only.

Comment: What elements are involved here? you said scrollView and UIImageView? and are you using nix or xib?

Comment: Using storyboard, I have a parent view > scrollview > then a bunch of subviews which contain all the labels and an image view which stretches (some images are are huge which is why I used aspectscalefill)

Comment: are you adding all the elements to the scroll view in the storyboard or by code?

Comment: Adding all the elements through storyboard

Comment: Most of the answers I found set the width by using trailing bounds, but my imageview automatically stretches horizontally if the width is not explicitly set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a single view application, and added a `UIScrollView` in the storyboard with four constraints (top, left, right, bottom). And I add the following code in the `viewDidLoad()`. Everything works just fine. My image is only scrolling vertically, but not horizontally. No additional settings are needed.

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Just as an example, I make a size with same with of the view
    // and twice the height of the view.
    let size = CGSizeMake(
        self.view.frame.size.width,
        self.view.frame.size.height * 2);

    // Load an image and make a image view
    let image = UIImage(named: "im.jpg")!
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(
        origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
        size: size);
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;

    // Add the image view to scroll view
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    scrollView.contentSize = size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a scroll view with auto layout try this.  No code at all so you will have to drag things out of the library to the right of Xcode.

In your view controller drag and place the scroll view size it to whatever you want but it looks like you want to make it the size of the screen.  Pin all edges to the edges of the view controller.  Pin trailing, leading, top, and bottom.

Now, instead of placing your items in the scroll view, place another view in the scroll view.  With this new view you will place all of your items. You will most likely have to move the view up or down to place them all and resize the view.  You can then place whatever constraints you want on your items.  When all items are in their place, set the frame of the new view back to x = 0 and y = 0.

You will then place constraints as follows.  Select the new view and pin to top, bottom, trailing, and leading and then center in container.  This will make a constraint that is vertical with some negative number.  In the storyboard outline select this constraint and set it to zero.

You will now be able to scroll vertically.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you! After a few tutorials and even a book, no one provided the key to not wanting to scroll horizontally.  It is adding that constraint to the view where you center it in the container. Thanks @Douglas

Comment: Not a problem!  Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem i caused by the fact that you add your elements to the scrollView from the storyBoard.

In the storyBoard you need:

1) Add the scrollView, if you need to be in the width of the screen then set it's trailing and leading spaces to superView to 0

2) uncheck the "allow horizontal scrolling" in the attribute inspector

In your code

1) set the `scrollView's` `contentSize` to what ever size you want it to be.

1.1) in your code you need to set the size of the contentView like so

```
scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(your width, your height);
```

This is a very important step, the scrollView will not be able to scroll if you don't set the size. Think about the scrollView as the window and the contentView as the view. If the contentView if the same size as the scrollView then the scrollView can't scroll anywhere (all of the contentView fits into the scrollView) in order to create the scrolling you need to make the contentView bigger then the scrollView itself

2) start adding your elements to the `scrollView's` `contentView` by calling

```
[scroller addSubView:<your view>];
```

this will add your views to the `scrollView's` `contentView` and will be

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I implemented it exactly as you detailed in your answer. But it is not scrolling vertically. Should I have dragged the views into the scrollview in storyboard too? http://i.imgur.com/XK5cYdH.png

Comment: what is the size of your contentView?

Comment: `contentView` is pinned to the `scrollView` (all 4 constraints)

Comment: Thanks but how can I make the contentView width the width of the device. And the code cgrectmake produces an error. I ended up using cgsizemake, but the width still expands.

Comment: @James first you are right i got confused with CGRectMake, you need to user CGSizeMake. If you want the width of the device, and you placed your autolayout correct, then call CGSizeMake(scroll.bounds.size.width, your height)